# Can't remove all newlines from a string - last one still remains

Tags: php, regex, newline

I quite never post here, since I always find an answer in other posts... but this time nothing works, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I need to var_dump a variable to a string. I found `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()` in php manual to achieve this.

For text-logfile/debugging needs, I want all \n, \r, multiple spaces and so on to be cleared.

My searches on SO brought me solutions like

```
$r = preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', trim($r));
//or
$r = trim(preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $r));
//I even tried this:
$r = trim(preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', trim($r)));
```

But I can get rid of the last newline character with none of these solutions.

Here the code of the function:

```
function var_dump_to_string ($v,$style='normal') {
    ob_start();//use buffering to catch direct output from var_dump()
    var_dump($v);
    $r=ob_get_clean();
    if($style=='flat')//just a flat string with no \r\n nor extra whitespaces
        $r = trim(preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', trim($r))); 
    return $r;
}
```

There's still an undesired newline in my textlog. I tried to var_dump the result of this function, there really IS a newline in it...
What am I missing?

**EDIT : the (working) function now looks like this**, thanks to @vks and @anubhava answers:

```
function var_dump_to_string ($v,$style='normal') {
    $r = var_export($v, true);
    if($style=='flat')  $r = preg_replace('/\s+|\s$/', ' ', $r);
    return $r;
}
```

Comment: can you give an example of the content `$r` ?

Comment: It's a general function intended to be used anywhere for anykind of variables I could have to log. I tried it with "null" (reason why var_dump and not print_r), with some arrays (reason why it has to drop all newlines), there's always a newline at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\s$
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.

```
\s+|\s$
```

Comment: It works, but only if I do it after my initial replacement: `$r = trim(preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', trim($r)));  $r = preg_replace( '/\s$/', ' ', trim($r));`

Comment: Tested and adopted (though replaced by one single space instead of empty string). Thanks a lot. See whole function code in edited question (using `var_export()`, thanks to @anubhava too).

Comment: Subsidiary question: why do I need to specify that the ending newline `\s$` should match too? Why didn't this newline match the general `\s+`?

Comment: @fpierrat it should.maybe you can post your input string so that it can be debugged.paste your input at regex101.com and share the link

Answer (score 1):

Use [**var_export**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) function instead to get return value of a variable definition in a string:

```
$ret = var_export($v, true);

// code to replace newline etc:
$ret = preg_replace('/\s+$/', '', $ret);
```

Comment: var_export is much better than my ob_start. As for the replacement, it just replaces the last newline, not the other ones (for instance when exporting array variable).

Comment: If you want to strip all newlines then use: `$ret = preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/', '', $ret);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
$r = trim(preg_replace( '/(\r)?\n(\s*)?(\r)?\n/', ' ', trim($r)));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:** `preg_replace("/\r\n|\r|\n/", ' ', $r)`

Code:

```
function var_dump_to_string($v, $style='normal'){
    ob_start(); //use buffering to catch direct output from var_dump()
    var_dump($v);
    $r=ob_get_clean();
    if($style=='flat')//just a flat string with no \r\n nor extra whitespaces
        $r = trim(preg_replace("/\r\n|\r|\n/", ' ', $r)); 
    return $r;
}
```

**Solution 2:** `str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $r)`

Code:

```
function var_dump_to_string($v, $style='normal'){
    ob_start(); //use buffering to catch direct output from var_dump()
    var_dump($v);
    $r=ob_get_clean();
    if($style=='flat')//just a flat string with no \r\n nor extra whitespaces
        $r = trim(str_replace(PHP_EOL, ' ', $r)); 
    return $r;
}
```

"PHP_EOL" includes all the "end of line" characters. This solution is the best approach to replace "end of lines" characters.